# How to fire an onApper method when a sheet close?

Tags: swiftui

I'm currently developing an application using SwiftUI.

I want to use an `onAppear` method when a `sheet` created from the same struct close.

Is there any way to do this?

---

Here are the codes:

BaseView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct BaseView: View {
    
    @State var isSheet:Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            VStack{
                Text("BaseView")

                Button(action:{
                    isSheet = true
                }){
                    Text("SHEET")
                }
            }
            .onAppear(){
                print("onAppear fiered")
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isSheet){
                Sheet()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sheet.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct Sheet: View {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {

        Button(action: {
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }) {
            Text("CLOSE")
        }
    }
}
```

---

Xcode:Version 12.0.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just move everything from `onAppear` into separated function and call that function on sheet dismiss as well, like

```
var body: some View {
    VStack{
        VStack{
            Text("BaseView")

            Button(action:{
                isSheet = true
            }){
                Text("SHEET")
            }
        }
        .onAppear(){
            foo()       // << here !!
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isSheet, onDismiss: {
            foo()       // << and here !!
        }){
            Sheet()
        }
    }
}

func foo() {
   print("do some here")
}
```